# Ping Federate Identity Provider

Tags: ping, federated-identity

I am new to setting up ping federate identity provide configuration and writing code to get token. I have got a ppt file which explain how web client connects to ping federate server and get token. and they mention to pass client_id as param but I have no idea what is client_id?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

`client_id` is your **user identity**. When you call `writetoken()` method, it has parameters to pass... hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using OAuth2 or OpenIdConnect and calling PingFederate to get an Access Token.

First, here is a detailed explanation of what a client is [RFC 6749 Client Registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) and its role in this authentication protocol.

Second, once you understand this topic. You must configure Clients on Ping. For that you must follow their documentation [Client Management](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/Client+Management).

Finally, You must point your web application to the OAuth2 endpoints passing the `client_id` and `client_secret`, with that depending on which OAuth2 flow you are using will get you closer to get an access token. You can find more information about that on Ping Documentation Site.

Hope this helped.